# How do I access non id property of request inside form requests?

Tags: laravel

I want to access route request parameters inside laravel form requests authorize. I cant find an example describing this.

```
// Works fine when you want id 
dd($this->route('myResourceName'));

// How to do when I want something else???  
dd($this->route('anotherAttribute'));
// Above give null probably because it is a resourceful controller
```

On a side note, I dont understand this design, whats the point?
$this->route('anyAttribute') would be the easiest, right?

Edit: more extensive example

```
class UpdateSlotAPIRequest extends APIRequest
{
    public function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct();         
        $this->slot = Slot::find($this->route('slot'));
        $this->access_token = $this->route('access_token'); // this is not working!
    }    
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        // If administrator is logged in all is good.
        // If slot is free its ok.
        // If its not free but you provide good access_token its also fine.
        return Auth::check() || $this->slot->isAvailable() || $this->slot->isValidAccessToken($this->access_token);
    }
...
```

```

Comment: what does `arbitrary request parameters` mean? you mean route parameter?

Comment: Correct just a route parameter!

Comment: can you add example of how you used it. Are you calling this from controller or middleware?

Comment: @omisakin-oluwatobi example added

Answer (score 1):

```
$access_token = request()->input('access_token');
```

Found it in https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers

Comment: Hope this is a good lesson. If you have any issue, try to make your first point of sear the documentation then... **search** stackoverflow, then if no solution even after *googling* then ask question...

Comment: The solution requires a global helper, I  suspect it is not the best solution. The documentation of form requests does not cover my use case, and no relevant seatch results hence the question.

Comment: so do you mean you cannot just say `$this->get('access_token')` in the FormRequest class? I thought `this` is an extension of the base Request class as well?

Comment: Yes it is! I found the issue in my code was where trying to extend the constructor and using $this->route before $this was instanciated. Doh!

Comment: I mean you can use `$this->get('access_token')` instead of calling the `request()` helper function because you are in Request's child class

Comment: yes, but then I cant use it in the constructor as i wanted